# Laravel Authenticate middleware differences between5.x and 7.x

Tags: laravel, authentication, redirect, middleware

I'm upgrading an app written using Laravel 5.3. The existing code has:

```
class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest((Request::segment(1) == 'nm' ? 'nm/' : '') . 'login');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

When I build an 7.x app it generates:

```
class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to proceed. What is the correct way to do redirects if the user is not authenticated in Laravel 7?

Comment: the method you are showing is one way way to do it ... what about it are you not sure of?

Comment: Well I wasn't sure if the original code would still work in Laravel 7. I'm a little further along and have been able to test it and it works, So no issue after all. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Old code still works in Laravel 7.